# как вы улучшите этот код для чтения/записи в CSV?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода, csv, io

```py
class csvr:
    def r(filename):
        o=open(bytes(filename),"r")
        X=o.readlines()
        file1=X
        file1
        file2=open(filename,"w")
        #lines=TextIOWrapper.readlines(file1)
        o.close()
        return dict(raw_data=X)

    def w(filename,data:list[str]):
        handle=open(bytes(filename),"w")
        
        v2=[]
        wq=""
        index=0
        v2=data
        for i in v2:
            handle.write(i)
            handle.write("\n")
        handle.close()
        return wq
```

Comment: Зачем вы экономите буквы? Что вы потом делаете с сэкономленными?

Comment: Ну и в целом это какой-то бессмысленный код, я бы его просто целиком выкинул и написал заново, извините.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разверну ответом

1. Имя класса с прописной буквы, пример `Csvreader`
2. Именя методов должны быть осмысленные, пример `read_csv_file`, `write_csv_file`
3. `__init__` для объекта класса объявите, присвойте туда сразу например имена для записи и чтения файлов или еще нужные поля
4. Использовать конструкцию с `with` для чтения и записи, пример

   ```py
   # reading
   with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
   ```
5. Принцип одной отвественности. Фкункция/метод делает одно действие, например или читает, или записывает, или сортирует данные по колонке и тд и тп. У вас первый метод и читает и записывает.
6. Используйте осмысленные имена переменным. Задайте вопрос перед тем как назвать переменную: что это? ответ переведите на английский, вот вам осмысленное имя
7. Если вы используете данную конструкцию

   ```py
   def w(filename, data:list[str]):
   ```

   придерживайтесь для всего объявления функции, тогда

   ```py
   def w(filename:str, data:list[str]) -> str:
   ```
8. Пишите строки документации.

После того, как приведет в порядок лексику языка, можно будет к логике вернуться